# double sum of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I have $ c_{1},...,c_{n} \in \mathbb{C} $.
Can I say that:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{j}\overline{c}_{k} \geq 0 ?
$$
Thank you.

Comment: Let $c_1=1,c_2=-2$

Comment: sorry, I had mistake there. Now it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n c_j\overline c_k=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\sum_{k=1}^n\overline c_k=S\overline S\ge 0, \text{ where } S=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j.$$